# How can i apply sqlcipher to JavaSE

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlcipher

I found sqlcipher is convenient to be used in Android development. But it's does not meet my need.Recently,i got a task to encypt a sqlite database in a project based on Java SE. The core of my question is "How can i apply sqlcipher to JavaSE."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no JDBC driver for SQLCipher at the moment.

Comment: But shouldn't there be a good chance to get on of the existing JDBC drivers for SQlite running?